# Select "To" and "From" dates with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to use a datepicker and choose "from" and "to" dates in it (in the same picker and selection).

I've read I can use "multipledatespicker":
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/##simple-select-days-range-demo

Is there any other (**simple..**) way of doing this with jQuery UI datepicker, and without using multipledatespicker ?

Comment: how you will differentiate whether its from date or to date if it is in same datepicker? why not in different `datepicker`? any specific reason?

Comment: What's important to me is that I will have one control shown, no matter how many datepickers i use in the codebehind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used one such plugin [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), hope this helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better you go on this link: [Demo](http://bseth99.github.io/projects/jquery-ui/4-jquery-ui-datepicker-range.html) and for Code :[Code](https://github.com/bseth99/sandbox/blob/master/projects/jquery-ui/4-jquery-ui-datepicker-range.html)
. Hope this will Help you to Find Better Solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try bootstrap-datepicker: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker